# Scss extraction with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, webpack

I am trying to use ExtractTextPlugin to extract and convert my scss to css and move it to `src` folder along with client.min.js , but currently getting the following issue when building webpack.config.js file:

> ERROR in ./scss/styles.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'main.scss' in C:\Users\ajoku\Desktop\Web Projects\learn2node\http\scss
>    @ ./scss/styles.js 3:0-20

My webpack.config.js file :

```
"use strict";
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('./scss/main.scss',{allChunks: true});
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "http"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: {
    js:"./react/client.js",
    scss: "./scss/styles.js",},
  module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
          }},
        {test: /\.scss$/i, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!scss')},
      ]
    },
  output: {
    path: "./src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css', {
            allChunks: true
        })
  ]
};
```

My styles.js file

```
require("main.scss");
```

My scss files are located in `http/scss` along with styles.js file
What could be causing the problem?Thank you for your time.

Comment: `require("./main.scss");` ?

Comment: well as i assume, i cannot just feed scss to webpack, so i need to import it somehow else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with sass-loader and extract-text-webpack-plugin

#### webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'http/scss'),
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&localIdentName=[name]-[local]!autoprefixer!sass')
    }
  }
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[hash].min.css')
  ]
}
```

#### package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0"
}
```